# Instalar o PHPMYADMIN no linux com php5.6

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, lamp, apache

Olá, estou configurando uma maquina com php5.6, já instalei e configurei o apache, php5.6 e mysql, agora quero instalar o phpmyadmin, o problema é que ao tentar instalar por meio do apt ele irá instalar vários outros pacotes, entre eles alguns do php7.1, eu não sei se isso irá prejudicar em algo no ambiente já que eu já tenho esses mesmos pacotes na versão 5.6. Quero saber então se existe alguma forma de instalar apenas o phpmyadmin ou se mesmo instalando com todos os pacotes adicionais não prejudicará em nada a configuração da maquina. Abaixo deixo a saída do terminal ao tentar instalar o phpmyamin pelo apt.

```
andre@andre-desktop ~ $ sudo apt install phpmyadmin 
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dbconfig-common dbconfig-mysql libjs-jquery libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore php-gettext php-mbstring
  php-pear php-phpseclib php-xml php7.1-common php7.1-mbstring php7.1-xml
Pacotes sugeridos:
  javascript-common php-libsodium php-mcrypt php-gmp
Pacotes recomendados:
  javascript-common php-gd php-tcpdf
Os NOVOS pacotes a seguir serão instalados:
  dbconfig-common dbconfig-mysql libjs-jquery libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore php-gettext php-mbstring
  php-pear php-phpseclib php-xml php7.1-common php7.1-mbstring php7.1-xml phpmyadmin
0 pacotes atualizados, 14 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 322 não atualizados.
É preciso baixar 6.730 kB de arquivos.
Depois desta operação, 37,5 MB adicionais de espaço em disco serão usados.
Você quer continuar? [S/n]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte forma, instalei o pacote php5.6-mbstring, assim o phpmyadmin parou de pedir o pacote php-mbstring que por sua vez precisava dos pacotes php7.1-common, php7.1-mbstring e php7.1-xml. daí depois foi só instalar o phpmyadmin pelo próprio apt mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

A unica maneira que vejo como instalar sem baixar os tais adicionais seria baixar manualmente:

- https://www.phpmyadmin.net

E colocar em uma pasta configurado com VirtualHost ou na htdocs (se for ambiente de desenvolvimento)

Note que o Phpmyadmin requer as extensões:

- mbstring
- gd2
- zip
- openssl
- libxml

E é por isto que na sua instalação apareceu isto:

```
php-mbstring, php-pear, php-xml, php7.1-common, php7.1-mbstring e php7.1-xml
```

As outras dependências podem ser coisas que faltavam mesmo e/ou adicionais para algumas funções opcionais do phpmyadmin.

Comment: Eu tentei instalar pacote por  pacote que é necessário para o phpmyadmin, todos instalaram de boa até chegar no php-mbstring, que ao tentar instalar ele requere os pacotes php7.1-common php7.1-mbstring